# Can I run a .NET garbage collection from WinDbg?

Tags: memory, garbage-collection, clr, windbg, sos

I'm looking into why a managed process is using a lot of memory. Is there a way to run `GC.Collect(3)` from WinDbg, so that I can focus on the actual memory allocation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to run a .NET garbage collection from WinDbg, but I also don't think it is necessary.

See [Rico Mariani's Performance Tidbits - Tracking down managed memory leaks (how to find a GC leak)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ricom/) for information about finding out what kind of stuff is on your heap.

Additional possibly useful links:

- [When to call GC.Collect()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ricom/)
- [Scott Dorman - .NET Memory Management – Resources](https://web.archive.org/web/20160708092857/http://geekswithblogs.net/sdorman/archive/2008/09/14/.net-memory-management-ndash-resources.aspx)

Comment: I'm interested. Could you explain why you don't think it's necessary?

Comment: It isn't necessary because Rico Mariani's information about tracking down managed memory leaks describes a process to determine what may be leaking, or what is on the heap at any point in your application without having to force a GC.

Comment: Won't you often run into a problem with step 7 (of Rico Mariani's blog post) if you have lots of objects lying around that could be GC'd?  Seems like a common frustration to !gcroot object after object and find no reference chains at all.

Comment: @IV I agree - it's a real pain. I often use the 'disposed' flag as a proxy for this information but not all classes implement IDisposeable or use this flag in its implementation. For example: .foreach (obj {!dumpheap -type Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection -short}) { .printf "\n\n"; .printf "Object at: %p\nDisposed: %d", ${obj}, poi(${obj}+12a) & 0x00FF; }

Comment: In a huge dump, analyzing memory leaks without GC.Collect is very hard.

Answer (score 3):

I do not believe that you can trigger a GC from WinDbg.

Here are some useful tools that I have come to rely on for memory allocation tracking:

- [SOSEX](http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2007/06/19/great-sosex-a-phenomenal-net-debugging-extension-to-see-the-hard-stuff-steve-johnson-is-my-hero.aspx)  -- a further extension
  for WinDbg to complement SOS which
  adds !dumpgen to dump objects from a
  particular generation (great for
  figuring out what is on the LOH and
  in Gen 2) and the !refs command
  which will give the parent refs for
  an object.
- [.Net Memory
  Profiler](http://memprofiler.com/Default.aspx) -- this is a very
  useful tool when running
  interactively but it also contains
  an option to load from a dump file. 
  This gives a reasonably intuitive
  way to track through memory usage.  Easily worth the 250USD price but they also have a 14 day eval.

Answer (score 2):

WinDBG is first and foremost a Win32/Kernel Debugger. So you may want to try one of the managed debuggers, like [mDBG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229861.aspx). But I used to do .NET Debugging support for MSFT, and I've never needed anything like that to troubleshoot memory leaks.

Comment: First and foremost a Win32/Kernel debugger, surely?

Comment: "I've never needed anything like that to troubleshoot memory leaks" So what *did* you use?

Answer (score 0):

Hey Roger,  Hopefully your memory leak is resolved by now.  :-)

I would first be sure that it is "managed memory leak".  By that I mean that when you look at Performance Monitor counters **.NET CLR Memory -> # Bytes in all heaps** is increasing at the same rate as the **Process -> Private Bytes** counter for the same process.  If it is, then you can use the techniques described above.

If it is not, you may have a native leak that is a result of running managed code.  The most common that I have see is related to .NET Assemblies being loaded in the process and not unloaded.  This looks like a native memory leak in Perfmon.

I would suggest that you try running a Leak Rule in [DebugDiag](http://www.iis.net/downloads/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1286)and see what the memory report shows as the leaking callstacks.

Here is another great resource on the subject:
[I have a memory leak!!! What do i do? (defining the "where")](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/archive/2005/11/25/i-have-a-memory-leak-what-do-i-do-defining-the-where.aspx)

Thanks,
Aaron

Comment: It's solved. I used the techniques from the other answers to find out what was being "leaked". It was a load of PaintEventArgs objects or something. The cause: an animated progress bar that was redrawing 10 times a second. So it wasn't actually a leak, just a control using way too much memory.