# Forcing GC when using windbg/sos

Tags: garbage-collection, windbg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I run a .NET garbage collection from WinDbg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334174/can-i-run-a-net-garbage-collection-from-windbg)

I'm debugging a memory leak with windbg/sos and I cannot find a way to have sos force a garbage collection.  The list of sos commands does not seem to include gc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicate: [Can I run a .NET garbage collection from WinDbg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334174/can-i-run-a-net-garbage-collection-from-windbg)

There's also [Triggering a .NET garbage collection externally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101196/triggering-a-net-garbage-collection-externally)

Could someone edit that question to mention sos (e.g. "The list of sos commands does not seem to include gc.")

Comment: Sorry for the dup, I did a search but did not find the original question

Comment: No problem - I've added tags to the original.

Comment: Is there any value in keeping this question?  I think I should delete it.

Comment: Hmm actually, I still can't find the original question through SO

Comment: I suggest keeping the question until someone can add a reference to sos.